# expected input to be a number but got the list

Tags: netlogo

I'm doing an ABM model on couple bargaining. On it, some turtles calculate their utility by taking account of common resources (which are possessed by the undirected link between a turtle and his couple). The link was created with

```
  create-link-with turtle (who - 25)
```

and the utility is being calculated with

```
to W-Ut-compute
set utility ( Wworkprod * ([work] of my-links ^ (workneed / (workneed + houseneed))) * Mhouseprod * ([house] of my-links ^ (houseneed / (workneed + houseneed))))
end
```

The code checking worked, but the go button doesn't.

```
^ expected input to be a number but got the list [-2.1300000000000017] instead.
```

error while women 100 running ^
  called by procedure W-UT-COMPUTE
  called by procedure GO
  called by Botón 'go'

How can I use the link values on its variables to do the turtles calculations?

Regards, thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`my-links`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#my-links) is the agentset of all the turtle's links, `[work] of my-links` returns a list (albeit a list of only one item, since there is only one link).

If you want to extract the one link you're interested in from the `my-links` agentset, you can use [`one-of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#one-of):

```
[ work ] of one-of my-links
```

As the name implies, this will randomly select one of the turtle's links. But since there should be only one anyway, it will always be the same.